# How to use capital Commands in Vim/Emacs/Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, text-editors

I am frankly just 3 days old in the emacs-vim old .
I need to execute some commands

`S-M-; (executable-find "git") RET`

But cant figure out how to use those capitalized commands.

My keybindings are set to vim and i am using spacemacs currently.
I have been using ' SPC SPC ' and other lower case combinations to navigate for now but

I (being a newbie to the zone), am in dire need for help to figure out rest of the commands.

I would be very gald to hear any other related suggestions for using spacemacs efficiently and navigating through the interface too if possible.

And thanx in advance for even reading this post;

Comment: I am asking for what S- and M- is.
Though i dnt knw what RET stands for so it will be helpful if u can explain.

Comment: Emacs != Vim, they're two different text editors and their keybindings are completely different from each other. Your question is about Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation):

> `C-`
> means (press and hold) the Control key
>
> `M-`
> means the Meta key (the Alt key, on most keyboards)
>
> `S-`
> means the Shift key (e.g. `S-TAB` means Shift Tab)
>
> `DEL`
> means the Backspace key (not the Delete key)
>
> `RET`
> means the Return or Enter key
>
> `SPC`
> means the Space bar
>
> `ESC`
> means the Escape key
>
> `TAB`
> means the Tab key
>
> A notation such as `C-M-x` (or, equivalently, `M-C-x`) means press and hold both Control and Meta (Alt) keys while hitting the ‘x’ key.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was super helpful.